# How do I send APNS Push notifications to an iPhone from a C Microsoft PC app?

Tags: c++, push, apple-push-notifications

How do I send APNS Push notifications to an iPhone from a C++ Microsoft PC app? ...

There is information "out there" on how to send push notifications to an ios iPhone app from a Mac, and how to send WNS push notifications to a Microsoft phone... but does anyone have information or more helpful a code example of how to send push notifications from a Microsoft C++ MFC app running on a PC to an ios iPhone app?

Answer (score 1):

Late to party but still...

...Not as easy as piece of pie, you will need to play around a few days before you succeed.

First of all read [this thing from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1), and read it all.

And have a look to one of a good [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12).

The idea in a few words is - your backend push the notification to Apple Push Notification Service(APNS) over TCP SSLed channel. Then that crazy thing pushes the notification to iOS device itself.

Your app needs to register for the notification, and supply a token to your backend.

Apple dose things in this way because of security concerns, so this is your only option to go with.

Pretty straightforward if you read the docs. Best of luck to you with PNs ;)